# Thread.CurrentPrincipal Lost When Invoking Button Click Using .NET UI Automation

Tags: .net, ui-automation

I am attempting to use the .NET UI automation framework to automate some tests on a WinForms application. The application contains some WPF user controls.

On logging in to the application Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set to a custom principal that inherits from GenericPrincipal. This is then used for permission checking.

I have managed to automate logging in to the application and opening a form which hosts a WPF user control. At various points Thread.CurrentPrincipal is checked and returns the correct object with the custom type.

The issue occurs when I automate clicking a button on the WPF user control:

```
var btnNewSet = setBuilderView.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "btnNewSet"));
btnNewSet.SetFocus();
Thread.Sleep(1500);
btnNewSetInvokePattern = (InvokePattern) btnNewSet.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
btnNewSetInvokePattern.Invoke();
```

The button click event fires then my application throws an exception because Thread.CurrentPrincipal returns an object of the base type GenericPrincipal instead of the custom principal previously set.

There is nothing special about the above code - it's the same code I'm using to invoke WinForms buttons in the application.

If I stop my automated test just before clicking the button, then click the button manually with the mouse, everything is fine and the current principal has the correct type.

It's worth mentioning that the WinForms buttons in the application are wired up to standard click event handlers whereas the WPF buttons are bound to an instance of ICommand (e.g. ).

This looks like a threading issue but I can't figure it out.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?